# Token Macro that whispers back at whoever clicked it

Tags: roll20, tokens

I'd like to create a "Lookup" token that has one clickable macro for each condition. If you click the macro "blinded", it puts the rule for the blinded condition in the chat. This works fine, but to avoid flooding the chat it would be really nice if the macro would not put it in chat, but instead whisper it back to whoever clicked the macro. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A whisper-to-me macro is possible.

Since you have specified a token macro (i.e. an Ability in Roll20 parlance), you need to have a controllable token selected. Precede the text of the macro with the following whisper command:

```
/w "@{selected|character_name}"
```

This will whisper to the controllers of the character that token represents. It will not even go to the GM unless they are specifically listed as a controller. The quotes are necessary to work with names that have spaces in them.

My suggestion would be to create a Macro Character Sheet ([more info](https://app.roll20.net/forum/permalink/5924364/)). This is a sheet controllable by all players. Put each of your conditions as a separate ability on this sheet. Then create a Chat Menu ([more info](https://wiki.roll20.net/Chat_Menus)) to call up a list of the conditions. Make sure that all of these abilities are preceded by the above whisper code.

The tricky part is to get the universal Chat Menu macro you have created to show up for anyone. This is possible through creating a Collections Macro (the one in the sidebar), marking it as a Token Action, and making sure the permissions for that macro are set to All Players. The content of the macro is simply code that calls your Chat Menu ability (assuming your Macro Character Sheet is called "Conditions" and your Chat Menu ability is called "Condition-Menu", it would look something like this:

```
%{Conditions|Condition-Menu}
```

Many conditions have multiple paragraphs. Carriage returns and linefeeds break whispers in chat. To avoid this, you can either put them into roll templates, ex:

```
/w "@{selected|character_name}" &{template:npcaction} {{rname=Stunned}} {{description=A stunned creature is incapacitated, can't move, and can speak only falteringly.

The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.

Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.}}
```

Or surround the text with triple brackets:

```
/w "@{selected|character_name}" {{{STUNNED: A stunned creature is incapacitated, can't move, and can speak only falteringly.

The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.

Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.}}}
```